# Tags: gospels vs gospel

Tags: discussion

could we add a tag "gospel" to refer to issues surrounding the spread of the Gospel though not necessarily in regard to one of the four gospels.  I would have liked to use it for [this question.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/paul-apostle-to-the-gentiles-peter-to-the-jews-but-peter-brought-the-gos)

Comment: I've tagged the question [tag:gospel-message] pending any better suggestions here…

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of having a bunch of theological tags, [tag:gospel-message] is much better than just having a [tag:gospel] tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why the question has down-votes, it's a perfectly sensible suggestion isn't it? We have tags for [temple](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temple), [faith](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faith), [sin](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) and [jesus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus) so why not  [gospel](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel) (or as Ray suggests to avoid mistagging, [the-gospel](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-gospel) or [gospel-message](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-message))? I can imagine many other questions that could be asked that would use this tag, particularly concerning the book of Acts.

I'd say 'yes', let's create the tag for Sarah.

If you vote this down please give an explanation (or post another answer) so I can understand the arguments against.

Comment: I'd like to give some thought about preventing mistagging. It would seem like an obvious tag when asking a question about, say harmonization of the synoptics, where we would prefer [tag:gospels].  What about [tag:the-gospel]?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea and can see how it would be helpful. Ray's issue is the only problem I can see. I'm not sure the-gospel gets around it entirely, though. But it might be the best option.

- evangelism does but is too application based-it might welcome the wrong kind of questions and answers.
- missionary-work? Nope.
- good-news? Maybe, but seems a little Christianese.

Would this tag be applicable to this (made up) question?

In Acts 1:8, Jesus says "But you will receive power when the Holy Spirit comes on you; and you will be my witnesses in Jerusalem, and in all Judea and Samaria, and to the ends of the earth."

Was this prediction fulfilled in the Bible?

[A: Yes, Acts is even organized around the witnesses spreading out in this very pattern. They first preach in Jerusalem, then Judea. Then the Apostles teach in Samaria, and finally the gentile missions are undertaken, ending with Paul in Rome on trial for being a witness of Christ.]

Comment: how about [tag:gospel-message] (inspired by Sarah's answer)?

Comment: @JackDouglas, I like that.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to clarify both tags with slashes or parenthesis?

gospels (books of) vs. gospel (not the books of)
gospels/synoptic vs gospel/good news
gospels (the four) vs. gospel(message of)

If gospel were typed into the tag prompt both options would then appear and the questioner could choose.

Or, if the existing prompt were edited in the description to include both the synoptic gospel accounts and the message of the gospel that would suffice.

Comment: no, only a-z and '-' are allowed in tags. 'gospel-message' might be good though?